# jQuery Inputmask: Go through mask static part with keyboard arrows

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

In jQuery Inputmask plugin `"tabThrough"` setting exists. How can I add support for keyboard right and left arrow navigation? Now if in mask there are more than one static mask character together and we press arrow keys than cursor goes through this static part by one symbol per pressed key. I want to go through static part of mask to next or previous active part.

Example of mask: `"i[i[i]]  –  i[i[i]]"`. It contains 5 static characters: two whitespaces, one hyphen and two whitespaces again. If we specify first number and then press TAB key with enabled `"tabThrough"` setting, than cursor will move to next number position in range. I need same behaviour for arrow keys.

Comment: Nothing yet. Only searched in google.

Comment: I re-read your question and I did not get the idea. You might need to be more clear (in language)